# Neo4j filtering Cypher query on relationships

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to retrieve the paths from Airport(A1) to Airport(A3) based on their relationships, when the arrival-time is less than departure-time. 
 here is my console link http://console.neo4j.org/r/7cw8h0

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost right (you also misspelt your property value for `Airport A1`)

```
MATCH path =((A1:AIRPORT)-[Connections:Connect*]->(A3:AIRPORT))
WHERE A1.name='Airport A1' AND A3.name='Airport A3' 
AND ALL (i IN Range(0, length(Connections)-2)  
        WHERE ((Connections[i]).arrvTime <(Connections[i+1]).dptrTime))
RETURN extract(Connect IN Connections | Connect.flightcode)
```

Your console was also not shared correctly, here is a correct version:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/jfxnsj

This might also be interesting for you:

- http://maxdemarzi.com/?s=flights
- http://gist.neo4j.org/?6619085

Comment: Thanks a lot. And I really happy with the links, its really interesting.